# Replace Unicode (Tamil) string using Regular Expression C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, unicode, tamil

I'm implementing for Lexical parsing in Tamil Language.
I need to replace a Text Element value  by following condition

```
        string[] ugaramStrings = { "கு", "சு", "டு", "து", "பு", "று" };
        string[] tamilvowels =
            {
                "அ",// "\u0b85"
                "ஆ",//"\u0b86"
                "இ",//"\u0b87"
                "ஈ",//"\u0b88"
                "உ",//"\u0b89"
                "ஊ",//"\u0b8A"
                "எ",// "\u0b8E"
                "ஏ",//"\u0b8F"
                "ஐ",//"\u0b90"
                "ஒ",//"\u0b92"
                "ஓ",//"\u0b93"
                "ஔ"//"\u0b94"
            };
```

if any word having element from ugaramStrings and tamil vowel element by consecutive.
Is need to be replace ugaram string and return the value.

for eg.அமர்ந்**துஇ**னிது replaced as அமர்ந்**இ**னிது.
i.e துஇ=>இ

I've done it by checking next string element using [TextElementEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator.aspx) Class.
Is it any possiblity is avail so that replace it by using [RegularExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] ugaramStrings = { "கு", "சு", "டு", "து", "பு", "று" };
string[] tamilvowels =
{
    "அ",// "\u0b85"
    "ஆ",//"\u0b86"
    "இ",//"\u0b87"
    "ஈ",//"\u0b88"
    "உ",//"\u0b89"
    "ஊ",//"\u0b8A"
    "எ",// "\u0b8E"
    "ஏ",//"\u0b8F"
    "ஐ",//"\u0b90"
    "ஒ",//"\u0b92"
    "ஓ",//"\u0b93"
    "ஔ"//"\u0b94"
};

var rxTemp = "(" +
    string.Join("|", ugaramStrings) + ")(" +
    string.Join("|", tamilvowels) + ")";

var rx = new Regex(rxTemp);

string str = "அமர்ந்*துஇ*னிது";

// This will contain all the matches
var matches = new List<Match>();

string str2 = rx.Replace(str, match => {
    matches.Add(match);
    // Group[1] will contain the ugaram letter, 
    // Group[2] will contain the tamil vowel
    return match.Groups[2].Value;
});
```

it seems to work correctly. The `str2` will contain the replaced string while `matches` will contain all the matches

Note that ugaram characters are composed characters, for example, so each ugaram "character" uses two C# `char`s.

For example கு is 'க'   + 'ு'.

This is illegal:

```
char ch = 'இ';
```

This is legal:

```
string str = "இ"; // str.Length == 2
```

For this reason you can't simply `[குசுடுதுபுறு]` but you have to `(கு|சு|டு|து|பு|று)`.

Comment: Very nice. I tried to do it the [] way and got unstuck as you can imagine. I was wondering if there is any way to tell regex to operate on the grapheme rather than per single byte character - i.e. treat graphemes as characters? I tried variations of String.Normalize and setting the culture on the Regex without much luck.

Comment: @acarlon No, .NET regexes work on single `16bit char` (so sometimes half unicode char, for non-BMP characters), and don't handle directly full graphemes, so it isn't possible to do anything like that, sadly.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much. 'Single byte' should have been 'single char' in my comment.